# Children views having equal height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` with two buttons with text inside.
The `LinearLayout`'s and the buttons `layout_height` is `wrap_content`.

The text of one of the two buttons takes two lines unlike the other's which takes one line.

So at the end one of the buttons has a bigger height than the other which is something that I don't want.

I know how to solve this programmatically. So the reason I making this question is to know whether I can solve this through xml.

One possible solution is, for the button whose text is one line, set

```
layout_height="match_parent"
```

and it works fine.

But the problem here is that generally I don't know which button will occupy the biggest height.

In essence what I want to do is: having a LinearLayout with Views inside 
I want to set the height of all the children Views to be equal to the height of the View which when has its content wrapped has the max height.

And the question is if this is possible through xml?

An example XML. Also I forgot to add that I already have 0dp in the widths.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/some_string" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/some_other_string" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: To the one who suggested an edit: sorry it was rejected automatically because I made a subsequent edit.
If you can post it again I will accept it.

Comment: please add your layout xml

Comment: Although the question is more general I will add an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you search is `android:baselineAligned="false"`, this will avoid that the text are on the same baseline and the buttons will start at the same y position on the screen.

Here without `android:baselineAligned="false"`:
[image: without android:baselineAligned="false"]

And here with:
[image: with android:baselineAligned="false"]

However if you also want that both buttons are equal sized try this layout example:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="aaaaa"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="bbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

That will look like this:
[image]

Comment: So we can have wrap_content on parent and match_parent on the children?
Strange but nice. Thanks.

Comment: Yes out of the perspective of the child it will match the parent size

Answer (score 0):

**Use this thing to set weigh Sum and weight layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```