# Children views with equal height based view with greatest height

Tags: android, view, height

I am trying to reproduce to android something that is quite easy on ios.

I want to have views of the same height where the height is determined at run-time. The height of the views should be based on the view with the greatest height.

I found a similar question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871276/children-views-having-equal-height)) but it is based on buttons maybe the reason why my solution is not working.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    <!--Other views-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    <!--Other views-->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe there is a solution for this using the designer. **If not possible I think I might have to do it programmatically by finding the greatest height then assigning the height to the other views** (If you know how to do it I also will accept it as a valid answer).

UPDATE:

I drew 2 images to illustrate my problem. The gray area is the parent linear layout. The green area the children linear layout. The red areas are "the other views" as is commented in the layout above.

Actual result:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the Expected output image ? `android:layout_weight` can be a solution .

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Are you willing to use constraint layout, instead of linear layout?

Comment: if it works, why not

Answer (score 0):

I achieved a layout similar to your second image with the following adjustments

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <!--Other views-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <!--Other views-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--The linear layouts are only for representation.
    Constraint layout only hs direct children, baring a few.
    You can use packed chain for aligning the text views together in
    center vertical-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier_demo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/right_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <!--Other views-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/left_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier_demo"
        >
        <!--Other views-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_demo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_layout,right_layout"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Whatever amount of text you put in the text view, even the one on left side starts containing multiline texts, the right layout is adjusted.
This is achieved through **barrier** in constraint layout.

[This](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) page explains it in an awesome way.
One more thing you should avoid nesting inside constraint layout. 
The vertically centre alignment can be achieved by **package chain**

[This](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) medium article is a good source.

Comment: My co-worker decided to change the implementation slightly as he didn't want to spend more time into this, however I think this approach I proposed is better. So I will test this at home and if it works I will accept your answer